By default electron js has to show me the top menu when I touch the alt key
by default electron js has to show me the top menu when I touch the alt key, but I want to disable it but nothing works for me, I don't understand what to do
Here is my code:
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
    mainWindow = getMainWindow();
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
    mainWindow.webContents.send('update-info', `Checking for updates. Current version ${app.getVersion()}`);

    globalShortcut.register('F11', () => {
        console.log('F11 key is disabled');
    });
    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Alt', () => {
    })
});

My expectation is that when I touch the alt key the menu will no longer appear

Should it be CommandOrControl+Alt or just Alt? What happens if you do this? globalShortcut.register('Alt', (e) => { e.preventDefault()})

Referencing to the OS window management behavior ?

Alt key pressed comes with the from your OS window management behavior,
There are two options you can do
OP 01:
Remove your menu entirely from your app , if you need any global shortcut you can add a custom logic.
Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);

globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Alt', () => {
    // add any logic
});

OP 02:
Build your custom Menu with behaviors
const menuTemplate = [
    // add your labels and sub-menu with logics
];


const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

